# How do I check the users input in Python3?

Tags: python

So my code says this:

```
a = input("Choose a letter")

if a == "A" or "B" or "D":
cr = "false" 

elif a == "C":
  cr = "true"

if cr == "false":
 print("Sorry you did not asnwer correctly")
 import sys
 sys.exit()

elif cr == "true":
 print("Well done!")
```

But for some reason, whatever I put, it says it is wrong. Any help? I am new to python and have come from Lua.

Comment: "it is wrong", what do you mean to say. is program throwing error or showing incorrect output

Comment: Please try to provide the code as you wrote it - it is very badly indented and does not run this way.

Comment: To be a little bit more pythonic you should use this: `if a in ("A", "B", "C") : ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if a == "A" or "B" or "D":` this evaluates to TRUE always. Because `"B" or "D"` always evaluates to `TRUE` everytime. So this might boil down to `if 0 or 1 or 1` no matter what.

To fix this you need compare after every conditional operator.
`if a == "A" or a == "B" or a == "D"`:

Answer (score 2):

```
if a == "A" or "B" or "D":
   cr = "false"
```

Is wrong. You want:

```
if a == "A" or a == "B" or a == "D":
   cr = "false"
```

One nice thing you could do is this:

```
if a in [ 'A', 'B', 'D' ]:
   cr = "false"
```

Or even better rewrite your script to this:

```
a = input("Choose a letter")

if a == 'C':
 print("Well done!")
else:
 print("Sorry you did not asnwer correctly")
 import sys
 sys.exit()
```

Comment: `if a in {'A', 'B', 'D'}: ` is better.

Comment: @Austin not necessary, since `BUILD_SET` takes time, too. I'd use tuples.